# Flot charts - create a bar chart with gradients and "solid"-colored area

Tags: javascript, flot, bar-chart

I need to create a flot chart that looks similar to this (light-red area needs to be a gradient to get a fade-out effect):

[image: Bar chart]

The solid colored area is supposed to always have the same size, but the bars overall of course can be of different sizes. At the moment, my idea is that I actually have two bars for every visible bar. A solid colored one in the center of the bar and one gradually fading out behind the solid one.

I am aware that you can have gradients in flot, but my question is if there is a better way (have only one bar in the code for every visible bar instead of two) to do this. Is it possible to have a bar chart in flot that has a gradient but also has a fixed size, solid colored area in the middle?

Comment: I believe your "two bars" idea is a good way to implement this.  In addition, one thing I've done to "decorate" (in my case adding threshold lines) a chart is to provide my own overlay hook and draw it myself directly on the canvas.